# NTFS for Windows

Tags: windows, uninstall, ntfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

I want to install Windows to my computer. However, Windows needs NTFS -filesystem for hard disk.

I want to replace Ubuntu with Windows. How do I do that, because Ubuntu doesn't use NTFS, and Windows installation requires it.

Comment: @Eino Can't you just install gparted and create an NTFS partition, also windows should allow you to create one during installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format the hard drive as NTFS using an Ubuntu Live CD or USB.

Simply boot the Ubuntu disc and select 'Try Ubuntu'.
When you reach the desktop open `Gparted` or `Disc Utility` and format the hard disk as NTFS.

Comment: Doesn't work. :(

Comment: What bit doesn't work - try using FAT instead of NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

The formatting to NTFS can be done when you install Windows (I assume 7 or 8) from install media. See this link for details http://www.avoiderrors.net/how-to-format-and-reinstall-windows-7/

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your info, but the Format option is just gray, so it means that I can't do it during installation. :/

Comment: @Eino I suggest you to ask question about this problem in another site, probably on http://superuser.com. This problem is another which should be in another way

Answer (score 0):

Understanding that Ubuntu is already installed in the computer and if you don't wish to keep both Ubuntu and Windows (Dual Boot) Simply start the Windows Installation and format the whole disk in order to install.

Windows will list the partitions as "Unrecognized" and allow you to remove them if unwanted. After which you can choose whether to partition or not the hard disk drive in order to install. If you choose not to partition the disk, the whole disk will be used for the Windows Installation.

Make sure to backup whatever data you already have in Ubuntu before to remove the partitions.

Good luck!

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your info, but the Format option is just gray, so it means that I can't do it during installation. :/

Comment: In Windows Vista/7 you can use the "Drive Options (Advanced)" in which you can manage the partitions as mentioned here: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/operatingsystems/ss/windows-7-clean-install-part-1_10.htm adittionally you can connect your hard disk drive in a different computer, windows based and format the drive, then return the disk to the computer/laptop and start again the installer. Windows XP Process is easier indeed. If you can't remove the disk from the computer try a Windows Based Live CD (Pilitos comes to my mind) and format from within. Good luck!